# Cómo mostrar la primera imagen que contiene un div en otra etiqueta usando javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Me interesa mostrar la primera imagen del div clase 'loop' sin importar cúantas contenga este, en la etiqueta id 'image' teniendo en cuenta que las imagenes que se encuentran dentro del div 'loop' no pueden tener id.

todo esto usando javascript

```css
body{
margin: 0;
}
img{
width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
<img id="image" src="">
</div>

<div class="loop">

<img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-QdQ8C0vBjS0/V-qefEf1m5I/AAAAAAABa1w/wjvJsM7V5y4YvAinwZt5Ab9k-ruoiiNAgCLcB/s1600/Breathtaking-Instagram-Photographs-of-Germany-2-900x900.jpg">

<img src="https://kurrican.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/paisajekayak.jpg">

<img src="https://k38.kn3.net/taringa/1/7/8/8/1/6/71/edf2012/0F8.jpg?1182">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aqui te comparto un codigo sin jquery y sin utilizar ID.

```js
// Obtengo listado de imagenes que estan dentro del div class='loop'
imagenes = document.getElementsByClassName('loop')[0].getElementsByTagName('img');

// asigno primera imagen a img id='image'
document.getElementById('image').src = imagenes[0]['src']
```

```css
body{
margin: 0;
}
img{
width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
<img id="image" src="">
</div>

<div class="loop">

<img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-QdQ8C0vBjS0/V-qefEf1m5I/AAAAAAABa1w/wjvJsM7V5y4YvAinwZt5Ab9k-ruoiiNAgCLcB/s1600/Breathtaking-Instagram-Photographs-of-Germany-2-900x900.jpg">

<img src="https://kurrican.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/paisajekayak.jpg">

<img src="https://k38.kn3.net/taringa/1/7/8/8/1/6/71/edf2012/0F8.jpg?1182">

</div>
```